# MacBook: how to edit an existing Terminal remote connection

Tags: ssh, mac-osx, terminal

On my MacBook I have close to a hundred remote connections in the list. Recently, I've changed the user I am using for all those remote connections and was wondering if there is a possibility to edit the user for those remote connections. At the moment, I can only remove and add new ones, but it will take time to do it for 100+ connections.

Here is the screenshot of the Terminal window with my remote connections:
[image]

The goal is here to replace all red color users with a new one without having to remove / add all existing saved connections.